# Jetpack Compose: Button resizing based on parent node

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, chain

What is the process by which button resize and share space evenly based on the size of the container they are in? What kinds of modifiers do you need to introduce?

[image]

Comment: Can you explain better what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three types I can immediately think of.  Here are the instructions for each:

- [Arrangement](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement)
- [Alignment](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/alignment-lines)
- [Modifier.align()](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers-list)